# Skype UWP camera too dark - ok in Camera app/ Skype desktop

Tags: skype-for-windows-10

I found out that I appear really dark in Skype UWP (Skype for Windows 10). There's no way to adjust brightness or any other camera settings from within it.

However, the same camera works great in Camera app or in Skype desktop. In both, it starts dark, but immediately auto-adjusts to good brightness. In camera app I can adjust the brightness, and Skype Desktop has a whole bunch of settings - but neither take effect in Skype UWP.

I found several such reports in [Microsoft forum](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/all/skype-brightness/fa3db9f5-cac8-4219-86aa-8778603a6576), with no solution other than move the Skype Desktop.

- Windows 10 Version 1803 build 17134.407
- Skype UWP App version 14.34.81.0
- Skype Desktop version 8.34.0.78
- Camera App version 2018.824.60.0
- Camera: Microsoft LifeCam Cinema, driver version 5.20.102.0 (2016-01-07)

Answer (score 1):

There are some claims for success in this area, but they have in common the
fact that adjustments can only be done *during a video call*.

One [post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/all/surface-studio-skype-video-dark/a9c446cc-2557-43d4-b9e3-9fbf160960ea?tab=AllReplies#tabs) says:

> I have discovered that Skype will actually lighten its picture automatically - but it takes time:
>
> Once your call is answered by the other party (receiver), during the
> first 20 to 40 seconds your picture will remain dark and then suddenly
> it clears and it adapts itself correctly and as you would expect it.
> Thus after 20 to 40 seconds the picture goes to normal.

Another [article](https://ccm.net/faq/10703-skype-adjust-the-settings-of-your-webcam)
says:

> Skype users can make variations in the webcam settings. One can make these changes, whilston a video call through Skype easily. All the user has to do is go to the webcam settings and start fine-tuning the brightness. Once, the desired result is achieved, press on OK and then exit. With this, the quality of the video conferencing will be greatly enhanced.
>
> Skype allows you to adjust the settings of your webcam; you may have noticed that whilst making a video call via Skype, the image from the webcam was too dark. You can modify the brightness level, Gamma....etc to suit your preferences.
>
> - On Skype, select *Tools > Options > Video Settings > Webcam settings*
> - Move the sliders to adjust the brightness level (or any other option to your convenience).
> - Validate with the OK button.

(Disclaimer: I'm not using Skype, UWP or desktop. There are better alternatives.)

Comment: Thanks. First post doesn't work for me. The other applies to Skype desktop.